# Convert hashtag into link in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to convert hashtag into link in UITextView? I already did some research but did not find a solution. It's like twitter and facebook. I don't know how to start developing it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use NSAttributedString. To add a link to a UITextView, you would need something like

```
    var string:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "#some one here")

    string.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http://www.google.com", range:NSMakeRange(0, 5))
    textView.attributedText = string
    textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link
```

Also, make sure to set your UITextView as not editable. This way it will directly open the link when clicked.

If you want, you can implement delegate method, where you can decide to open the link or not. 
Set your class as your delegate for UITextView and implement the following function

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView
shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
         inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

In this function, you can go to your other UIViewController.

More help at [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:)

Comment: let say if there are 100 hashtags, how possibility to do it? The content is  dynamic, not static.

Comment: For all the 100 hastags, do you have links as well?

Comment: actually it's not a link, it will redirect to another view controller

Comment: For that you need to implement the delegate method. In that you can decide to open URL or to redirect to view controller.
If you want to add more strings, you can use appendAttributedString

Comment: How to use appendAttributedString?

Comment: [string appendAttributedString:anotherString] 
This will give you two string concatenated in one.